# search in an array for a variable in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a loop on the array that contains some of bus seat numbers.
but it always returns with false.

```js
alert(response.reservedseats.indexOf("1"));//this line works and gives true
for (i = 1; i < 13; i++) {
  if ( response.reservedseats.indexOf(i) > -1 ) { //This always gives -1 and there are some true conditions so it's give not found
    alert("done");
  }
  else{
    alert('not found');
  }
}
```

Comment: try `.indexOf(i.toString())` or `.indexOf(i+'')`

Comment: @omarmosad - it's hard to debug this without presenting a full-self-contained example. give us what is in `response.reservedseats` and it should work fine?

Comment: Java has no relationship to javascript. Please remove the java tag.

Answer (score 0):

What's likely happening is that your array of objects is an array of strings, while in your for loop, you are attempting to find the index of the number - "1" is not the same as 1.

The easiest way to fix this would be to convert the number to a string.

```
"" + i;
```

and then use this in place of i

```
if ( response.reservedseats.indexOf("" + i) > -1 ) {
```